# how to set placeholder as an object in textarea element?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set placeholder in `<textarea/>` so to appera like this

```
{
  "name": "jon",
  "job": "developer"
}
```

I tried to assign placeholder in variable and then call it in placeholder

```
const placeholderText = 
`{
   "name": "jon",
   "job": "developer"
}`
```

But i think there's a better a way of doing this, especially when the values of keys in the object are too long this could break the line.

Comment: It's unclear what your question is about. Can you post the code that is not working, and the behavior that you'd rather expect from it?

Comment: Okay, now I get it, you want to maintain line breaks and leading spaces in a multi-line template string. I think Tholle's answer is the simplest way to achieve iff the string has to represent a JSON-encoded object. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep the placeholder in a regular object and use `JSON.stringify` with some indentation for the `placeholder` prop.

**Example**

```js
function App() {
  const placeholderObj = {
    name: "jon",
    job: "developer"
  };

  return (
    <textarea
      placeholder={JSON.stringify(placeholderObj, null, 2)}
      rows={10}
      cols={30}
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This works. However, the problem you'll have with placing so much info (instructions) within the textarea is that as soon as the user enters the first character of input, all of the placeholder copy is gone. This Mozilla link discuses this and other issues further: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Labels_and_placeholders